# download and untar file than check the content, async await problem, node.js

Tags: node.js

I am downloading a file in `tar` format with [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) module. Then I untar that file with [tar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar) module using `async await` syntax.

```js
const list = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
   const filePath = "somedir/myFile.tar.gz";
   if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
     const options = {
        uri: "http://tarFileUrl",
        encoding: "binary"
     };

     try {
       console.log("download and untar");

       const response = await rp.get(options);
       const file = await fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
       file.write(response, 'binary');
       file.on('finish', () => {
         console.log('wrote all data to file');
         //here is the untar process
         tar.x(
           {
             file: filePath,
             cwd: "lists"
           }
         );
         console.log("extracted");
       });
       file.end();
     } catch(e) {
       reject();
     }
     console.log("doesn't exist");
  }
}

//here I am checking if the file exists no need to download either extract it (the try catch block)
//then the Array is created which includes the the list content line by line

if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
  const file = await fs.readFileSync("lists/alreadyExtractedFile.list").toString().match(/[^\r\n]+/g);

  if (file) {
    file.map(name => {
      if (name === checkingName) {
        blackListed = true;
        return resolve(blackListed);
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    console.log("err");
  }
}
```

The `console.log` output sequence is like so:

> download and untar 
>   file doesn't exist 
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...lists/alreadyExtractedFile.list' 
>   wrote all data to file 
>   extracted

So the file `lists/alreadyExtractedFile.list` is being checked before it's created. My guess is I am doing some wrong `async await` actions. As console.logs pointed that out the second checking block is somehow coming earlier than the file creating and untaring processes. 
Please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to call `resolve` inside `new Promise()` callback.
2. If you write a local utility and use some sync methods, you can use sync methods whenever possible (in `fs`, `tar` etc).
   This is a small example where a small archive from the Node.js repository is asynchronously downloaded, synchronously written and unpacked, then a file is synchronously read:

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const tar = require('tar');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const url = 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest/node-v11.10.1-headers.tar.gz';
    const arcName = 'node-v11.10.1-headers.tar.gz';

    const response = await rp.get({ uri: url, encoding: null });
    fs.writeFileSync(arcName, response, { encoding: null });

    tar.x({ file: arcName, cwd: '.', sync: true });

    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('node-v11.10.1/include/node/v8-version.h', 'utf8');
    console.log(fileContent.match(/[^\r\n]+/g));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

```
  const file = await fs.readFileSync("lists/alreadyExtractedFile.list").toString().match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

the `readFileSync` function doesn't return a promise, so you shouldn't await it:

```
const file = fs.readFileSync("lists/alreadyExtractedFile.list")
    .toString().match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

This should solve the issue